# Spring Data Jpa save() can not isnert value with id auto_increment

Tags: java, spring, h2

I'm leaning the h2 database with spring data jpa, when i use the query it works

but when i insert the object,it doesn't work

error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into t_user (id, password, username) values (null, ?, ?)
```

user entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      path: /h2-console
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/db/testDB
    username: root
    password: 123456
    platform: h2
    schema: classpath:schema.sql
    data: classpath:data.sql
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: false
    database: h2
```

my UserController:

```
@GetMapping("/save")
    public List<User> saveUser(){
        User user  = new User();
        user.setUsername("json");
        user.setPassword("123");
        userRepository.save(user);
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

scheme.sql

```
drop table if exists t_user;
create table t_user
(
    `id`       int primary key auto_increment,
    `username` varchar(255) not null,
    `password` varchar(255) not null
);
```

please give me some suggests.

I solve the problem
i need to change the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = Gen erationType.IDENTITY, generator = "increment")`

and now it works

Comment: are you executing the scheme.sql to create your table instead of letting hibernate create them for you?

Comment: [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql#:~:text=3.%20The%C2%A0schema.sql%C2%A0File) is what you are looking for.

Comment: now i create the table with hibernate it still fails,but if i chage the GenerationType.IDENTITY to GenerationType.AUTO it works,why is this

Comment: What is your version of Hibernate ORM (`hibernate-core`)? This issue was fixed in recent 5.6.* releases.

Comment: the `hibernate-core` version is 5.4.12

Comment: These old versions don't work well with new versions of H2, you need to use some recent version, such as 5.6.10.Final or 6.1.1.Final.